# WooCommerce Hide Prices When Inventory is set to '0' or 'out of stock'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know I can use the css property 'visibility:hidden', to hide the prices on the product listing page (I have it assigned to a specific page id, only on the sold items page.

But on the individual product page is there a piece of PHP I can use that says something like "If item is out of stock/quantity is set to 0, then hide price"?

Main sold out product listing:
http://www.montagemodern.com/sold

**Individual Out of stock product page example:**
http://www.montagewestport.com/product/pair-of-glass-bubble-lamps/

Comment: Looks like the prices are still appearing on your sold products... I gave an answer to a similar question a earlier. You can view it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24767866/2867667

Comment: Why show the product at all?  If there is 0 stock, why not just hide the product completely?  Well, looks like you managed it anyways.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html", "theanand_remove_prices", 10, 2 );
add_filter( "woocommerce_variable_price_html", "theanand_remove_prices", 10, 2 );
add_filter( "woocommerce_get_price_html", "theanand_remove_prices", 10, 2 );

function theanand_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
        $price = "";
    }
    return $price;
}
```

http://wwweb.jextensions.com/theanand.com/blog%252Fhide-price-out-of-stock-woocommerce%252F

Comment: I also added: .outofstock .price{display:none;}