# Hide price in product listing if out of stock woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the price in the product list page of a `woocommerce` website, but I don't seem to make it work.

I want to hide the prices only for the items that I choose to be out of stock in the backend. all the other items should have the prices visible.

I need to do this in the product list page, not in the single product page. I already managed to do it there.

I came up with this code:

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) { ?>
    <div id="instockprice" class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></div>
<?php } else if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) { ?>
    <div id="outofstockprice" class="price" style="display:none;"><?php echo $price_html; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="whatever" class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm editing the `price.php` file located in the `woocommerce/templates/loop` folder.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Woocommerce "out of stock" items price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761778/how-to-hide-woocommerce-out-of-stock-items-price)

Comment: Sometime all it takes is a little research, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761778/how-to-hide-woocommerce-out-of-stock-items-price/24767866#24767866

Comment: I already did look into that thread, but it is related to te product page...
I need to do this in the product listing page with all the products (in and out of stock) with the prices for the ones in stock and without the price for the ones out of stock.